# Skip Shopify Statistics/analytics Collection while running tests

Tags: automated-tests, shopify

I'm starting to code some in-browser automated tests for our Shopify store, and I noticed that I've inadvertantly caused a massive traffic spike to our store during the time I was developing.

Is there a way to make a browser visit not count on Shopify analytics, like a "nostats" queryparam or something?  I may eventually end up with dozens of tests running maybe a dozen times a day, and that'll make a significant difference to our analytics.

Right now I'm testing against a previewed theme deployed with themekit, so I'm not testing against the live theme.

I could create a dev store and copy over all our products/collections/etc, but I'd really rather test as close to the live store as possible.  If that's stupid (or if there's a really easy way to make my dev store mirror my live store), let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to disable Shopify analytics or stop collecting data in any manner you would like to do this. So, you would definitely need to use a development store to run your tests.

There's a number of apps available for store data syncing/migration. That's an easy option but might be quiet expensive. Depends on your resources though.

You can also create your own solution to sync the entities you need for testing. Not so easy but good if you would want to apply this process to multiple Shopify projects.

Comment: Rats.  Thanks Vladimir.